# C# .NET console application opens web browser when debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

My C# .NET console application opens my web browser when Debugging, as well as the console itself. How can I set the project such that only the console opens, and not the browser?

Comment: Do you have a web application project in your solution as well? If so, it will be your Build Configuration.

Comment: @Adrian The project was previously a web application, and was modified to be a console application. Perhaps there was a setting that was forgotten to be changed...?

Comment: So I assume you have changed your project's Output type to Console Application, but did you change the project's type guid from a Web Project to a Console Application?

Comment: @Adrian The project type GUID in `.csproj.user` was changed from Web Application to C#

Comment: In the `.user` file? What about the actual `.csproj` file. The user file is your local settings only. It might be conflicting.

Comment: That was it! Silly mistake, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131202/discussion-between-user2181948-and-adrian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being caused by the project type GUID of the project file still being set to a web application, even though the project output is set to "Exe".

The `.csproj` file (not the .csproj.user file) will need to be manually edited to change the project type GUID to `{36761217-1D8E-4C0F-9A00-B86D9D12B086}` so that Visual studio will recognise the project as a C# application and not a web project, and will therefore not attempt to open a browser when the project is debugged.